# Intercepting user gesture Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently testing an Android app where I aim to intercept all user gestures and selectively allow only certain ones. The approach I've taken involves creating a service that inflates a floating view, which itself implements the onTouchEvent method. I have been successful in displaying the floating view and capturing touch events, however, I'm encountering an issue where the events are not being forwarded to the underlying view as I expected. To enable the events to propagate further, I've returned false from all the overridden functions (since this is the conventional way to allow events to continue). Despite this, the events are not being passed to the underlying view, and I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue.

```
 override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    windowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager

    val layoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        else
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or

                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    )

    val inflater = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    floatingView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.floating_view, null)


    // Initialize the GestureDetector and set the custom DoubleTapListener
    
    gestureDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, GestureListener())
    gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(DoubleTapListener())

    floatingView.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        // Forward the touch event to the GestureDetector for gesture detection
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)

        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && event.pointerCount == 1) {
            floatingView.performClick() // Perform the click action on the floatingView
        }
        // Return false to let the touch event pass through to the underlying view
        false
    }
    windowManager.addView(floatingView, layoutParams)
```

and exemple of gesture detector

```
 inner class DoubleTapListener : GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

    override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        // Called when a single tap is confirmed.
        val message = "Single Tap Detected!"
        val duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, message, duration).show()
        return false // Do not consume the touch event, let it pass through
    }

 inner class GestureListener : GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        // Called when the user first touches the screen.
        // Return true to indicate that the gesture is handled.
        return true
    }

    override fun onShowPress(e: MotionEvent) {
        // Called when the user performs a show press gesture.
    }

    override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        // Called when the user performs a single tap up gesture.
        Log.d("Gesture","Single Tap")
        return false // Do not consume the touch event, let it pass through
    }
```

I implemented all the methods but didn't copy them here.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can't do it. Your floating view is either fully click through or it consumes all touches. This was done on purpose to prevent keyloggers (or touch-loggers if that word exists).

Comment: See also "tapjacking" attacks. This has been blocked for over a decade at this point.

Comment: OK, sad to hear that, but learned something new. Thank you very much!